# User created schedules every X hours from start time

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, discord.js

I'm trying to write a discord bot in discord.js that lets the user schedule payouts to occur every X(1-730) hours from a given start hour of the day(0-23). I wanted to use cron times via node-schedule, but what if the user wanted something like every 77 hours?

Currently, the object i'm saving from the commands to the db is this:

`const jobParams = 
{   name: 'Job Title',
    currencyName: 'Credits',
    interval: '77',
    amount: '30',
    startHour: 5,
    member: '119351283999047682',
    role: null };`

The end goal here is to have a system that will schedule the job on startup to give the supplied member, 30 "Credits" every 77 hours (every 3 days 5 hours) with the counting from the next 0500. The payment transaction is ready to go.

The users will also need to be able to cancel jobs on demand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use steps in cron times. `*/77` is analogous to "every 77th." With this concept, you can start a cron job to run every 77th hour through *another* job that fires at the next 5 am (only once).

```js
const { CronJob } = require('cron');
const foo = () => console.log('Hello, world!');

const job = new CronJob('0 */77 * * *', foo);
new CronJob('0 5 * * *', () => {
  job.start();
  this.stop();
}, null, true);
```

Alternatively, you could have a cron job fire at every 5 am, and set a timeout to execute your code in 77 hours.

```
const job = new CronJob('0 5 * * *', () => setTimeout(foo, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 77), null, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using node-schdule https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

I haven't used it personally, but it seems like you can schedule some callback to occur after your period of time.

From the example on the page

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

You could then build some API around the scheduler to create / destroy schedules.

Comment: right, yeah I am using node-schedule, but that takes cron times and every 77 hours from the next 5am doesnt seem feasible